# Looping Solution through Dates (CVRP problem with ORTools in Python)

Tags: python, optimization, or-tools

We are looking to create a date loop for the CVRP solution.
We are uploading a months worth of orders (the demand), then create a unique route for each week of that month.

We cannot seem to figure out how to get the model print a solution for each week.
currently, it is printing the full solution for each day, using the code: "`for date in data['date']:`", under the "`print_routing_guide`" definition.

I feel like the date needs to be attached to the index somehow? or loop the dates around the "`solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)`"?

Would anyone know what code to use to solve this issue?

any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

**Please see the code we are using below:**

```
def print_routing_guide(data, manager, routing, solution):
    """Print solution on console."""
    print('\n')
    total_distance = 0
    total_load = 0
    for date in data['date']:
        print('\n')
        print('Date is: {}'.format(date))
        print('____________________________________________________________________________________________________')
        total_distance_days = 0
        total_load_days = 0
        for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
            index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
            plan_output = 'Route for vehicle {}:\n'.format(vehicle_id+1)
            route_distance = 0
            route_load = 0
            while not routing.IsEnd(index):
                node_index = manager.IndexToNode(index)
                route_load += data['demands'][node_index]
                load_weight = data['demands'][node_index]
                plan_output += '{0} ({1:,} lbs) -> '.format(data['location_names'][node_index], round(load_weight))
                previous_index = index 
                index = solution.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
                route_distance += routing.GetArcCostForVehicle(previous_index, index, vehicle_id)
            plan_output += '{0} ({1:,} lbs)\n'.format(manager.IndexToNode(index), round(route_load))
            plan_output += 'Distance: {:,} mi\n'.format(route_distance)
            plan_output += 'Weight: {:,} lbs\n'.format(round(route_load))
            print(plan_output)
            total_distance_days += route_distance
            total_load_days += route_load
        total_distance += total_distance_days
        total_load += total_load_days
        print('Total Distance: {:,} mi'.format(total_distance_days))
        print('Total Weight: {:,} lbs'.format(round(total_load_days)))
    print('\n')
    print('____________________________________________________________________________________________________')
    print('Totals:')
    print('Total Distance: {:,} mi'.format(total_distance))
    print('Total Weight: {:,} lbs'.format(round(total_load)))




def routing_guide():
    """Solve the CVRP problem."""
    # Instantiate the data problem.
    data = routing_guide_data()

    # Create the routing index manager.
    manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(len(data['distance_matrix']), data['num_vehicles'], data['start'], data['dummy'])

    # Create Routing Model.
    routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)


    # Create and register a transit callback.
    def distance_callback(from_index, to_index):
        """Return the distance between the two nodes."""
        # Convert from routing variable Index to distance matrix NodeIndex.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
        return data['distance_matrix'][from_node][to_node]

    transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(distance_callback)

    # Define cost of each arc.
    routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)



    # Add Capacity constraint.
    def demand_callback(from_index):
        """Return the demand of the node."""
        # Convert from routing variable Index to demands NodeIndex.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        return data['demands'][from_node]

    demand_callback_index = routing.RegisterUnaryTransitCallback(
        demand_callback)
    routing.AddDimensionWithVehicleCapacity(
        demand_callback_index,
        0,  # null capacity slack
        data['vehicle_capacities'],  # vehicle maximum capacities
        True,  # start cumul to zero
        'Capacity')




    #Number of locations per vehicle
    def num_of_locations(from_index):
        """Return 1 for any locations except depot."""
        # Convert from routing variable Index to user NodeIndex.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        return 1 if (from_node != 0) else 0;
    
    counter_callback_index = routing.RegisterUnaryTransitCallback(num_of_locations)
    
    routing.AddDimensionWithVehicleCapacity(
        counter_callback_index,
        0,  # null slack
        [ 5000 for i in range(data['num_vehicles']) ],  # maximum locations per vehicle
        True,  # start cumul to zero
        'num_of_locations')



    # Setting first solution heuristic.
    search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
    search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC)
    search_parameters.local_search_metaheuristic = (routing_enums_pb2.LocalSearchMetaheuristic.GUIDED_LOCAL_SEARCH)
    #search_parameters.solution_limit = 100000000
    search_parameters.time_limit.FromSeconds(1)
    search_parameters.log_search = False

    # Solve the problem.
    # Print solution on console.


    solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)
    if solution:
        print('Solution Found:')
        print_routing_guide(data, manager, routing, solution)
        
    else:
        print('Solution not Found!')


#data['date']
#sorted(df["Shipment Create Date"])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    routing_guide()
```

Comment: what routing_guide_data() contains ? all location for a day ? a week ? a month ?
Does each location are associated to a day or can be served any day in a week or in a month ?
If you can split your problem by week or day you should do it unless you want some "month optimization"

Comment: The routing_guide_data() contains all the location data for each day. 
All the locations can be served any time with in that week. 
The dates that are entered into the routing_guide_data() are the dated the orders (the demand) were summited by the customer.

We are hoping to print out results for all the weeks or of month, or year, for analysis